# Python - Man in the Middle

Tags: python, scapy, man-in-the-middle

I want to catch a packet my computer is sending, modify it and send it. I can't use sniff, because it gives me a copy of the packet. The packet itself is sent.
I want to stop the sending of the packet, change it and then send it forward - MitM attack.

How can I do it using scapy?

Comment: You have a project here(https://code.google.com/p/scapy-arp-mitm/), check it out

Comment: @tweellt, it says that there is a bug in libdnet that prevents Scapy from running on Windows Vista and later versions of Windows. I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

What you need sounds more like a proxy. What kind of protocol you try to inject into? If it was HTTP it would be easy - take any HTTP proxy and mitm away.

Or you can use something like socksify, but I am not aware of anything working on Windows. Or you need something that works as a network driver.

You cannot easily achieve this with scapy if packets originate from YOUR computer. Example with scapy-arp-mitm is performing mitm on other computer communication.

Comment: I'm trying to inject to SIP protocol